# I cannot change user account control (UAC) setting as an administration

Tags: windows-10, uac

I cannot change UAC to "Never notify me". I logged on as an administrator, and this is the message I got:

> You must be logged on as an administrator on this computer to select this setting

[image]

[admins group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtLa8.png)

Comment: You do understand that setting does not disable the UAC prompt right?  You will still receive UAC prompts even if you set the setting to "Never notify me"

Comment: @Ramhound Are you sure? I didn't have this problem before. UAC did not notify me when I want to open something like change name of user, but now...

Comment: Am I sure that changing the notification setting for UAC will NOT disable UAC prompt, I am absolutely positive, that the notification setting WILL NOT disable UAC.  That can only be accomplished through a group policy and will disable ALL UWP applications.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not want to disable UAC prompt. I just want to disable the notifications that will appear on my screen.

Comment: Can you show which user groups your user is a member of as a screenshot? I was making sure you knew, that the setting `Never notify me`, does not actually disable UAC on Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound I am the user named "M" https://pasteboard.co/2TgFrQqU8gFd.png

Comment: You are going to need to use the image upload feature and edit your question.  pasteboard.co is blocked in my region.

Comment: @Ramhound done!

Comment: This machine connected to an AD domain by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound what is AD domain? excuse me for this question :)

Comment: @Ramhound I think the answer is NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the behaviour you describe when not logged on as an administrator, the message is absolutely correct.

As soon as I log into Windows as an administrator, I can change the UAC Settings to the lower two settings as well.

Just running the `User Account Control Settings` dialog elevated as an admin is not enough. You actually have to log in as an administrator to change all settings.